# Force Windows to use only TCP for DNS lookup

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system

I have a broken (badly configured) VPN network that I cannot change. The remote gateway will route all UDP traffic for port 53 to a special DNS service. But I need to use a different DNS server also on the remote network. I know that TCP queries will not be altered and reach the correct server. Please note I need a solution on OS level. A proxy will not be enough.

Can I configure Windows (XP/7/8) in a way that it will use TCP instead of UDP for name resolution?

Comment: Your best bet may be a firewall/packet filtering rule that REJECTs (not DROPs), all packets destined to UDP port 53. The firewall will generate an ICMP administratively prohibited destination unreachable message back to the DNS client. On receiving this error, the client might try again automatically with TCP. I don't know if that will work but it's worth a shot. Also, I can't help you create such a firewall rule, I only know how to do that with Linux iptables... but it ought to be possible with MS Windows too.

Comment: I wonder if you could configure a DNS forwarder on "your" side of the VPN, which will then use only TCP to queries to traverse the VPN.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. The issue is that the local machine is a random customer machine. Any major change would result in a major or minor problem itself. I regard this question now as unsolvable myself.

Comment: @Roman I think that's key information that should be in the question - that severely limits your options even further